# Ionic ion icons and UTF-8 miscellaneous symbols are not appearing inside Toast | Ionic ToastController

Tags: android, ionic-framework, utf-8, ionic2, ionic3

***Is there any solution for this ..?***

**Ion icons are not appearing in Toast**

[image]

**UTF-8 Miscellaneous Symbols are not appearing in Toast**

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Okay suraj, Do you need code?

Comment: for this site you will have to add the code directly..

Comment: As for this question.. the toast controller just shows text..It does not parse any ionic components..You can however give [css](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toast/ToastController/#advanced)

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestion.